# Spring mvc pagination how to get result

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I already have posted this post yesterday..but nobody answerd it..
I am using spring mvc framework.

I want to do pagination like the below picture:--
[image]

So I have done :--

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/detailssection/id",method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody  String showthedetails(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{

//I want to display 5 details per page

                    int recordsPerPage = 5; 

 //It will count total no of records(like 300 records are there)

  int totalnoOfrecords = viewService.TotalnoOfRecoredsbanglains1();

//If the totalnoOfrecords=300 then page noumber will be 300/5=60 that means 1,2....60           
int pagenumbers = (int) Math.ceil(totalnoofrecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);   

                         map.put("detail", new Detail());
                        map.put("noOfPages", pagenumbers);
                        map.put("detailList", viewService.viewDetails());



            return "detailssection";
        }
```

and my jsp page is like:--

```
 <div id= "part1">

 <div id= "details">
        <p>${detail.description}</p>
   </div>


    </c:forEach>

  <%--For displaying Previous link except for the 1st page --%>

   <c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
      <a href="/detailssection/id?pagenumber=${currentPage - 1}">Previous</a>
    </c:if>



    <%--For displaying Page numbers. 
    The when condition does not display a link for the current page--%>

            <c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
                        ${i}
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <a href="/detailssection/id?pagenumber=${i}">${i}</a>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>


    <%--For displaying Next link --%>

   <c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
        <a href="/detailssection/id?pagenumber=${currentPage + 1}">Next</a>
    </c:if>

</div>
```

But I am not getting any page numbers.its only showing the "previous page" section.Its like:--
[image]
what am I doing wrong?Is there any problem in jsp page??

Comment: if you want index of the current iteration, you must use loop's `varStatus`, or if you have numbers in your noOfPages variable, to display it use `<c:out value="${i}" />`
P.S: like you did, it's not the way you access a map from JSTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the begining.

If you have a map on your `requestScope`, suppose it is `MyMap` with the following keys: `details`, `noOfPages` and `detailList`, to access it's values by keys, the syntax is the following:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="$MyMap['noOfPages']" var="i" varStatus="loop">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
            ${i}
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <a href="/detailssection/id?pagenumber=${loop.index}">${loop.index}</a>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @Salini be aware to access the map also by it's key, so if you set your map on the request like `request.setAttribute("myMap", MyMap);` you should retrieve it from requestScope by it's key `end="$myMap['noOfpages']"`